# Representing a B Tree in secondary storage

Tags: c++, data-structures, b-tree

I am writing a program to store and retrieve information from a B-Tree on disk that contains strings as keys and I am having trouble finding a way to represent the tree on disk. I thought of storing every node of the B-Tree as a .bin file on disk and create additional data structures(hash-table) in-memory that map the pointers of the children to the corresponding file names on disk. Are there better schemes out there that can efficiently represent a B-Tree on disk? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: research term:  persistent storage

Answer (score 0):

Use a single file. The whole point of a B-tree is that it is suitable for disk storage. Use a fixed node size of say 2k bytes and constrain the B-tree order accordingly so that N keys and pointers fit into a node, along with whatever per-node housekeeping data you need. You will need a file header that tells you where the current root of the tree is and the head of the free list.